Derivative with respect to an index within a summation
First note that
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n}}{n!} \, x^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}, $$
where $(a)_{n}$ is the Pochhammer notation. The background is how to evaluate the series, and related series,
$$ S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)_{n}}{n!} \, \left( \psi(n+1) - \psi\left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right) \right) \, x^n. $$
One method of evaluation is to consider
$$ \partial_{n} \left( \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n}}{n!} \right) = - \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n}}{n!} \,  \left( \psi(n+1) - \psi\left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right) \right) $$
which leads to
\begin{align*}
S &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)_{n}}{n!} \, \left( \psi(n+1) - \psi\left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right) \right) \, x^n \\
&= - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n \, \partial_{n} \left( \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n}}{n!} \right) 
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[ \ln(x) \, \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n}}{n!} \, x^n - \partial_{n} \left( \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n} \, x^n}{n!} \right) \right] \\
&= \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{1-x}} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \partial_{n} \left( \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n} \, x^n}{n!} \right).
\end{align*}
This then leads to the question of the problem. A series that involves a derivative with respect to the index of summation inside the summation. How to evaluate the series
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \partial_{n} \left( \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n} \, x^n}{n!} \right) \quad ? $$
Also note that Mathematica, or Wolfram Alpha, provides the result of the series as:
$$ S(x) = \frac{\ln(4 (1-4 x))}{\sqrt{1-4 x}} - {}_{2}F_{1}^{(0,0,1,0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}, \, 1; \, 1; \, 4 x\right) $$
which is the same as:
$$ S(x) = \frac{\ln(4 (1-4 x))}{\sqrt{1-4 x}} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n}}{(n!)^2} \, H_{n} \, (4 \, x)^n. $$

I dont see how you can differentiate with respect to $n$ when $n$ isn’t free.

Leucippus, I think there was a misunderstanding with this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4965240/can-infinitesimals-be-used-to-complete-the-rational-numbers and I think it merits re-opening.
