Can infinitesimals be used to complete the rational numbers?
Suppose we start with the rational numbers and, much like is done in nonstandard analysis, adjoin what I will call a Q-infinitesimal to the the rational numbers and call it the hyperrationals. Here a Q-infinitesimal is a positive number that is less than every positive rational number and greater than zero.  Can the hyperrationals be used to get the real numbers?

What is your opinion to the question?

The real numbers don't have a number smaller than every rational.

@Cheerful, nonetheless the answer to the question is affirmative; see Nicholas's answer.

@MikhailKatz true, and interesting. To be fair, I was interpreting the question to be "Is this number system isomorphic to the reals?", which I don't believe was an unreasonable interpretation.

The title of this question reads: "Can infinitesimals be used to complete the rational numbers?"  The answer is unambiguously affirmative and is the only reasonable interpretation. @Ch

$
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\ext{{}^*}
\newcommand\Q{\mathbb Q}
\newcommand\Z{\mathbb Z}
\newcommand\Fin{\mathrm{Fin}}
$As others have said, such a number system cannot be isomorphic to the reals.
However, you can construct a hyperrational number system; its nonstandard hull is then precisely $\R$.
Nonstandard analysis is not just something that gives you infinitesimals in $\mathbb R$; it is a whole system that gives you nonstandard objects in any set you choose. Speaking informally, for any set $S$ there is a nonstandard extension $\ext S \supseteq S$ which "has all the same properties as $S$ if you replace every set with its extension". This is the Transfer principle. For example, the Archimedean property for $\Q$
$$
  \forall x, y\in \Q.\:\exists n\in\Z.\:nx \geq y
$$
is also true for $\ext\Q$ in the sense that
$$
  \forall x, y\in\ext\Q.\:\exists n\in\ext\Z.\:nx \geq y.
$$
It may look from this like there can be no infinitesimals in $\ext\Q$, but the hyperintegers $\ext\Z$ contain infinite elements; the "proper" Archimedean property
$$
  \forall x,y\in\ext\Q.\:\exists n\in\color{red}{\Z}.\:nx\geq y
$$
is false in $\ext\Q$.
There are other nonstandard principles which essentially guarantee that certain nonstandard objects exist; I'm not going to get into anymore of that here.

You define infinitesimals in $\ext\Q$ much just like you would $\ext\R$
$$
  \mu(0) := \{\epsilon \in \ext\Q \;:\; \forall x\in\Q.\:|\epsilon| < |x|\}.
$$
We say that two hyperrationals $x, y$ are near each other $x \simeq y$ if their difference is infinitesimal, i.e. $x - y \in \mu(0)$. We write
$$
  \mu(x) := \{y \in \ext\Q \;:\; y \simeq x\},
$$
called the monad of $x$. Note that $x \in \ext\Q$ is not necessarily standard.
The key to the nonstandard hull construction of $\R$ is that not every monad contains a standard rational; these are the "gaps" in $\ext\Q$ which cause it to be incomplete. Thus, we can take $\R$ to be exactly the set of all monads, with each "gap monad" corresponding to an irrational. More precisely, we take the finite part of $\ext\Q$,
$$
  \Fin(\ext\Q) := \{x \in \ext\Q \;:\; \exists y \in \Q.\: |x| < |y|\},
$$
and quotient it by the relation $\simeq$:
$$
  \R := \Fin(\ext\Q)/{\simeq} = \{\mu(x) \;:\; x \in \Fin(\ext\Q)\}.
$$
Because $\simeq$ respects all arithmetic operations when restricted to $\Fin(\ext\Q)$, e.g.
$$
  x \simeq y \iff x + z \simeq y + z,
$$
you can show that $\R$ inherits a field structure, as it should.

Unfortunately no, we can't use infinitesimlas to complete the rational numbers. The real numbers are complete, since every Cauchy sequence has a limit in $\mathbb{R}$. However the hyperrationals, as you defined them are not complete in this sense because they include infinitesimals, which are not limits of any Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$.
The infinitesimals are not complete nor continuous, so we cannot construct an isomorphism to the real numbers.

It's true that the hyperrationals are not isomorphic to the reals, but we can take their nonstandard hull to construct the reals.

The answer by Nicholas is very detailed but I wanted to provide a dumbed-down version thereof.  If $F$ denotes the space of finite hyperrationals, and $I\subseteq F$ denotes the space of infinitesimal hyperrationals, then $I$ is a maximal ideal in the ring $F$.  One can therefore form the quotient $F/I$ which is an ordered field.  This field is canonically isomorphic to $\mathbb R$, answering your question in the affirmative.
